# C++11 random numbers and std::bind interact in unexpected way

Tags: c++, gcc, random, c++11, stdbind

I am using GCC 4.6.3 and was trying to generate random numbers with the following code:

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng_engine;

    printf("With bind\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
        auto rng = std::bind(dist, rng_engine);
        printf("%g\n", rng());
    }

    printf("Without bind\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
        printf("%g\n", dist(rng_engine));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expected both methods to generate a sequence of 5 random numbers.  Instead, this is what I actually get:

```
With bind
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
0.135477
Without bind
0.135477
0.835009
0.968868
0.221034
0.308167
```

Is this a GCC bug?  Or is it some subtle issue having to do with std::bind?  If so, can you make any sense of the result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When binding, a copy of rng_engine is made. If you want to pass a reference, this is what you have to do :

```
auto rng = std::bind(dist, std::ref(rng_engine));
```

Comment: Not fair, I had a call from mom before posting
+1 for speed.

Comment: Damn, I cannot just answer with a smiley :)

Comment: Slightly off topic, but what if you wanna use bind and pass a generator by reference to each std::thread?

Comment: If you pass the generator by reference to different threads, you might get in trouble : as the generator has an internal state you will have concurrency problems. Therefore mutex and headaches. It would be safer to give each thread its own generator (with different seeds)

Comment: Ahh!  Of course, makes sense.  I had seen this pattern from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and cplusplus.com (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).  Might be worthwhile to correct it there as well if anyone knows how.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `std::uniform_real_distribution::operator()` takes a `Generator &` so you will have to bind using std::ref

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng_engine;

    printf("With bind\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
        auto rng = std::bind(dist, std::ref(rng_engine));
        printf("%g\n", rng());
    }

    printf("Without bind\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
        printf("%g\n", dist(rng_engine));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`bind()` is for repeated uses.

Putting it outside of the loop...

```
std::mt19937 rng_engine;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
auto rng = std::bind(dist, rng_engine);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    printf("%g\n", rng());
}
```

... gives me the expected result:

```
0.135477
0.835009
0.968868
0.221034
0.308167
```